# DetailReportBand in devexpress returns null reference c#

Tags: c#, devexpress, report

I am using `extra report devexpress` to create my report ,in my report i want to pass two datasources to my report as you can see :

```
DetailReportBand MaterialRequestContractor1 = report.Bands["DetailReport"] as DetailReportBand;
            MaterialRequestContractor1.DataSource = lstMaterialRequestContractors;

            DetailReportBand MaterialRequestContractorDetails1 = report.Bands["DetailReport"] as DetailReportBand;
            MaterialRequestContractorDetails1.DataSource = lstMaterialRequestContractorDetails;
```

But this part be initialized with `NULL` why? In fact i don't know what is `report.Bands["DetailReport"]` .And what should i set instead of `DetailReport`

Comment: No one can answer this question /

Comment: If you have created DetailReport band then you can simply find it's object i n report's designer.cs file.. you have no need to get it from bands collection.